# Convert Windows-style path into Unix path

Tags: java, path

I want to take a string that represents a path and convert it to an absolute Unix-style path. This string could be in either Windows or Unix styles, as it's the result of a call to `MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()`, which returns different style paths depending on your system.

(I'm doing this for a game I'm writing, a portion of which gives the user a simple "bash-ish" shell, and I want the user to be able to read files. The fake filesystem is stored as a normal directory tree in a subdirectory of my project. This filesystem is going to use Unix-style paths, and I want to be able to concatenate inputted paths with the aforementioned string (with some minor edits to get it into the right directory) so I can find the contents of the files.)

Any ideas how I might go about doing this? I've tried a number of things, but I can't seem to get it to work properly on my friend's Windows 7 system.

At the moment I'm just using a simple thing that checks to see if the string starts with "C: \" or something similar and then replaces backslashes with slashes, but there's no way that that can be a good way to go about this, and I'm sure other people have faced the problem of different path styles before. It's certainly a very temporary solution.

Comment: i would suggest showing some code, what you are trying to achieve, and what you currently have.

Comment: The question appears reasonable enough to me without code.

Comment: Perfectly sensible question. org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.normalize(name, true) will do what's required. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do, and instead of explaining why a user shouldn't, why not post the answer?

Answer (score 16):

In general, I never had problems on any operating system with using a '/' as separator.

```
 new File("/a/b/c.txt");
```

works at least on Unix, Windows and iSeries.

If you want to be correct, there's a constant 'File.separator', that holds the operating systems separator.

If you want to replace the backslash '\' in a string, remember that it is a special escape character:

```
String newString = str.replace("\\","/");
```

**edit:**

and remember, String is immutable.

```
 str.replace("\\","/");
```

will not change the string, only return a new string with the replaced characters.

Comment: Hint: using the `char` version of `.replace()` will be slightly more efficient :)

Comment: OS separator character: Path.DirectorySeparatorChar

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is be able to access a file with a relative name to a certain directory, you can just use plain [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) API, like this:

```
final String baseDir = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
final String relativeName = "audio/abc.mp3";
final File relativeFile = new File(baseDir, relativeName);
final String canonicalPath = relativeFile.getCanonicalPath();
```

It should work on both Unix and Windows, since Windows accepts both Unix- and Windows- style paths (just saying it from my own experience).